# How to get RAM working in dual dynamic paging mode?

Tags: memory, motherboard

My motherboard is Intel D865GVHZ.

I'm using 512 MB RAM, and recently, I purchased 512 MB RAM from the same company, same speed(333) and same manufacturer.

However, my PC is not booting in dual dynamic paging mode. It is not booting at all, and the screen freezes on the windows logo screen at start up.

I installed the RAM one by one, and the PC is working with either of the RAM sticks installed individually.  When I install both the PC is not working.

One more point, I found that my one RAM module has 8 chips on both sides while the other one has 4 chips on both sides. Could that be the root of the problem?

Comment: This is not a programming question and this is not the first time you have asked a non-programming today.

Answer (score 1):

[Your motherboard have some restrictions.](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d865gvhz/sb/CS-027109.htm)

> Double-sided DIMMs with x16
>   organization are not supported

Just like one of your modules...

Comment: it will be really grateful if you please elaborate the terms so that i can understand the matter more better i request sir please cz i m just a student and not familliar to the technology and terms .

Comment: Modules with 16 memory chips on board called "DIMM with x16 organization". Such modules are restricted for your motherboard. As far as i'm concerned you have one module of that type. So you need to exchange it and get module with 8 chips.